# Laravel 5.1 whereNotNull with join not working (returning all data)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to Select all non empty columns in 'user' table where column name is 'review'.

```
$applications = DB::table('users')
    ->join('applications', 'user.update_id', '=', 'applications.id')
    ->whereNotNull('users.review')
    ->select('user.id', 'user.rating', 'user.appid', 'user.review', 'applications.title', 'applications.price', 'applications.icon_uri')
    ->orderBy('user.id','asc')
    ->paginate(20);
$applications->setPath('');
return $applications;
```

But return data includes all information of both 'user.review' empty and not empty as well.

I feel there is no effect of `whereNotNull()` and i found no error in the statement.

I tried moving `->whereNotNull('user.review')` this line top and bottom result is same.

I tried even by removing select and orderBy but returns same data.

```
$applications = DB::table('users')
    ->join('applications', 'user.update_id', '=', 'applications.id')
    ->whereNotNull('users.review')
    ->paginate(20);
$applications->setPath('');
return $applications;
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your table is **users** you are missing an *s* in the table name, you should write

```
->whereNotNull('users.review')
```

same case in the *join* with the field *update_id*, otherwise you have to change the table name in the table method

Comment: Nope that's not the issue. I edited question once again.

Comment: the column in the database really have NULL values or are just empty?

Comment: It worked that is the only issue rows are empty.Not null in database